# Splitting a sentence in words where word(s) also include multiple spaces by using regular expression

Tags: java, regex

Having a sentence with multiple spaces by using regular expression I try to achieve the following:

example of sentence: This     is a simple text.

**Expected result**:`[This,     is, a, simple, text.]`

**Actual result**: `[This, is, a, simple, text.]`

```
ArrayList<String> tokens = new ArrayList<>();
Pattern tokSplitter = Pattern.compile("[a-zA-Z.*//s*]+");
Matcher m = tokSplitter.matcher("This     is a simple text.");
    while (m.find()) {
            tokens.add(m.group());
    }
    System.out.println(tokens);
```

Comment: Sorry, you have 5 spaces between `This` and `is`, right? And you want to all of them to be there before `is`? Should the whitespace be kept before each item? So, should it be `['This','     is',' a',' simple',' text.']`?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew sorry I made I typo. It should be:
expected result:[This,&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;is, a, simple, text.]

Comment: Try this pattern: `\s*\S+`, so it will be `Pattern tokSplitter = Pattern.compile("\s*\S+");` Here is [demo](https://regex101.com/r/9fmiAp/1)

Comment: @kishkin thanks a lot. You did it :-)

Comment: Maybe just `s.split("(?<=\\S)(?=\\s)")` would do? Or `s.split("(?<=\\S)\\s")`?

Comment: When asking a question, use words and be precise.  When to leave and not leave leading spaces and how many is still unclear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write something like:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ArrayList<String> tokens = new ArrayList<>();
    Pattern tokSplitter = Pattern.compile("(\\s*[a-zA-Z.]+)\\s?");
    Matcher m = tokSplitter.matcher("This     is a simple text.");
    while (m.find()) {
        tokens.add(m.group(1));
    }
    System.out.println(tokens);
}
```

out: `[This,     is, a, simple, text.]`

Answer (score 2):

I think using [lookaround](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) is the simplest way to solve your issue.

```
Pattern tokSplitter = Pattern.compile("(?<=\\S)\\s");
String str = "This     is a simple text.";
ArrayList<String> tokens = Arrays.asList(tokSplitter.split(str));
System.out.println(tokens);
```

Answer (score 2):

You are using the wrong tool for the job. If you want to split a string, use the `split` operation:

```
List<String> tokens = Arrays.asList("This     is a simple text.".split("\\b "));
```

This produces a list with the same contents as the [currently accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60954702/2711488). It’s worth noting that both solutions consume one delimiting space and only keep additional spaces whereas the output of `System.out.println(tokens);` is `[This,     is, a, simple, text.]` because the `toString()` method of all standard `List` implementations inserts a space after each comma.

If you want to retain all spaces, you would have to use

```
List<String> tokens = Arrays.asList("This     is a simple text.".split("\\b(?= )"));
```

instead. The actual result strings can be seen when using:

```
tokens.forEach(s -> System.out.println('"'+s+'"'));
```

```
"This"
"     is"
" a"
" simple"
" text."
```

compared to

```
"This"
"    is"
"a"
"simple"
"text."
```

of the other solutions.

If you want to deal with `Pattern` directly, e.g. to be able to reuse it, it still doesn’t stop you from using `split` instead of a match loop:

```
Pattern wordEnd = Pattern.compile("\\b(?= )");
List<String> tokens = Arrays.asList(wordEnd.split("This     is a simple text."));
tokens.forEach(s -> System.out.println('"'+s+'"'));
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple pattern to solve your task: `\s*\S+`

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/9fmiAp/1).

The code will be:

```java
ArrayList<String> tokens = new ArrayList<>();
Pattern tokSplitter = Pattern.compile("\\s*\\S+");
Matcher m = tokSplitter.matcher("This     is a simple text.");
    while (m.find()) {
            tokens.add(m.group());
    }
    System.out.println(tokens);
```